# Not sure about image on JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have already tried the following =
`ImageIcon clear = new ImageIcon ("icons\delete1.png");`

```
JButton clearBT = new JButton(clear);
```

And it works perfectly, I just have a question to make. The directory of the image is into my hard disk, but I want to deliver my project to my professor, so I am not sure if the image will still show up when in his computer. The thing is that I am not sure if the directory that I've put in my code (which exactly is "`C:\\Users\\George\\Desktop\Giorgos\\icons\\delete1.png"`) will have something to show on my professor's pc.

Comment: add the image to your project, say in a `res` folder, and give the relative path instead of the absolute path.

Comment: Just bundle the code and the images in a jar and deliver it. Let the path to the image(s) be relative.

Answer (score 1):

If Your Professor's PC has internet access then you can use something like

(Please upload your file somewhere on internet like [imgur](http://imgur.com) and pass that url of your image  `new URL(here)`)

```
URL lenna =
            new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png");

ImageIcon clear = new ImageIcon (URL);
JButton clearBT = new JButton(clear);
```

Answer (score 1):

If icons folder is in project directory folder and in code you are calling the image with :

ImageIcon clear = new ImageIcon ("icons\delete1.png");

And It's working perfectly ,then It will work anywhere.

Just Make sure you are not calling the image location address as its complete address that is referring to  your computer hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Put the picture in you projects and you will have to change your code to

```
JButton clearBT = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(image_path)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to ship the image bundled with your source code. For instance, create a "package" / directory inside your project hierarchy and store images there.

Then, you can load them this way:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/the/image");
```

For instance, if the image is under org/example/program then the above will be:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/org/example/program/image.png");
```